# Install Symfony on distant server

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, lamp

I try to instal symfony on a distant ubuntu server (I'm connecting to it by ssh) so I install PHP7.2, LAMP, composer and symfony.

Next I launch symfony server using: `php bin/console server:run` and it says

```
[OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Where `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/` is the adress of the server :
When I go to the adress : `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/phpmyadmin/index.php` I get the phpmyadmin page
When i go to the adress : http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx : I get my apache page.

But how do I go to my symfony page? 
I try `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8000` but it's not working

I try to follow the information on this page: `https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html`

but when I do it I get the error :

```
php bin/console server:start 34.254.242.93:8080
```

And I still get the same error.

Comment: As the instructions make very clear, the builtin server is only for testing during development.  It will only response to browsers running on the same machine i.e. localhost.  Look in the docs to see how to configure your apache server to serve your symfony app.

Comment: Ok thank i will check that

Comment: did you try instead of http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8000 , use IP:8000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some resources available to deploy correctly your application:

- [Basic software installation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Configuring Web Server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)
- [Deploy Symfony Application](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#common-post-deployment-tasks)